# I cant generate pdf with fpdf and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Excuse my bad English.

I have a problem, I try to generate a PDF file with the fpdf library in a php (controller) passing before by an AJAX (jscript), but it does not generate the pdf but it generates this

```
PNG


IHDRd'©ñ :IDATxíAÇßFÊÆ
(l£Mb1ö`á\6ÓÆí!°gÉ-Ö$\Ârçl4öÁø0"¶7Y#´'BwQÌ
áY¬Äe1rÍ¡µ­ÞªêW¯ª«»§·ÿcõôT½÷êUõëWÕÕ³s³Íááa|ðjí9§ãÖ4îß¿_µ    ¨\¸p¡jf¹¹¹ôÇÓDô""zóø
áÕªM@¥£Ç~9<<üÓÖnµ¦TÂÒSòù`q19FÀty-Wb-®ÂÛbêÙ="iî1c-c.5JTÝY¹Qj
ø$ÃúìRTQÕ±bÅ#5kdë(ãûÅÅg-"Ì=rÒîÕ}Ë´+éÁt½¼ÒÑÆZ9iæÅÈpýúõv»MqÀú
Ñ¯¾ÿé¤j«*!@å~7®ohA÷¾º³#¼ða.l-+M½MÝÈ°vãäöë4ú³æÆ¤D~:¯LÓZä8áûÙhFr>+ú(JXËf^°,ÃÒ2F6ùÉ+fÅ)¡Ö¤1Æ'uÖX¿XÕN1ú*«øZ`
+!^Ãzã7L    aüMÇG¹q¿]~)\õ+I&%0È9£UdyB|e¡£¬a½¥ Ìäú'¿6¾­¨¹£   ¬a¥ÉaötOþ¸lBFÉ¶¬S?I­<4ób+o×¬+DÊAfõhUÄev¨ò¼É·ÉGö¬Z9iêÅhVVz¼f]!É±±þ­U"×åñ¤7ÞvRÅieØÏá·^g-f^ð°5¬2ÓL©Ârâ¨§   xJxB 4*TÅ4ób5¬B2¬2¯±^Ï'¦^&°æ³ª
ÈAa'RøÅQ@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔX+¢ôéóJ1æcíÁeúIfÊ5l¶É/v}xZùü<}~)ÙFéºé
GãI¨Ic£ ®:å¥fXåG+W¥ÆlK¿-èÅÒg²j¥IznåRÄ¢%»êÒR%y¢öPöxøGÞvW9m®º¬c#Ëå8T-I¿AÍ°fÄÉ­ÜâÊeÒ¯Ò:FáFE®­¤¤íIk4O·ÇØ.«ÍúU²ÑÖ2
[ªgÀsü81']JKí2jw­%ìÁ°®´îìîþçìÙ3wéÅ ü¯×Òc:z¨hg$[C¡R2>ÜÁüÊè6ëVÉ©q±ÁûÇZ]ÒR=ÆI,ô0^1F    ñNä«NJýr"½±Nýëß7ÚQ|¼´ôÃ~ÿMË/6,ÞCGYF¹ZÆ©à1¿VPaVèâTz<çô¡~¦~ÏûðÛ»FDtñâVëÔx¼Õí¾Â0ÂN¡FèªÆ0AD.ÙÉØ-ÆA/ôXÛ»W¢PÕÂsvVWXÕÊaõû$¢µµ¨ÓYØÞÞ¿víãñV{ûÃ¯/þ4yæ»7åéÔ($íÇà÷Õ¢%3¤µÝXÆ*ÙÏÒ,ñ^FèCIKõ±aÕ.!T/gy>-S¨Ki©N­ÃO®=¹þÌ×Wã÷úý÷£h~4z!>3ìÞ¸1iµÎF¿Á!(2I
ý/?®F÷ÚkDÔé<¹Wt:£Ñ&ýáðÖw°N2¥ÝTHð_ÃoM§ûQ4ßnKïv%¢Á`t¥u'¯u`    !Z2ñXW£{7oÞ¢£ôjsó¿Îv¯·3,/?½´Ô¢£å-gÀJ§WÉ£n÷_ãñt4ú²ß@D½Þ"mn~raïv@[
Ç'`)éÕx<M¾£h~uõ<õûïç´o%ûu'!Åüjì§Ô[xiùõ§ÝE<ÿvÂ¸wÄ»×ªm+y¬-bòø¬¬Õ+":{öñ*~§µZ§¶¶|sûCoãV^Ë¨v×LC(m5*kÛaèÛÖõQW¹Q¯v9?%¼Ýkß¼EGëDEóÉ·­Ö©ä Óúýýþû£Ñåü[ÒnUv]é«²`1àí'Nº²jåÌÒðöl¬¢ï÷ÃìÝ4½í~ö0ÝÇqc­ÅTÔÛ¥û'½C«YþqêwI-ïqhÅ9`ÅéÕÒRkyùéøL¤VWÏß¼ùEð-+Ç_,0vq¸óÛF]tÜûë/åzHØ®nµGâ%k+þwÅ¨ËolHòw«½ccµi¬µÿóþ´7&«]ÞãÐ[ÀºÒº³zó­­-$'/^<U¾×[ìt¶Ñ¨ýÒß¦/ø¨ 7"9}ä¤«4ÉéA&©åasúVÌGyå@×ÊcýÆ±5]ÊÌ?å+W?;¡Á8ÊCi    ãPÇ-`
£8½7.è¤§D§½Þ»/wûþf²½ÿoÌ·CáaÄo­·t¦V~í*ýîRVê/??K.0BÇ¡Ã¢ûÖÑèc:^Å$ñ+¾¥|oq·rnqðk¤µ
Xvf1ÊI'ÕéË© Öµ×ª®÷y?ÂÕ
öósAM
/aê8dXñ¯20éxÃpø°×{÷oþØÉ¸t/J_ôi¹>¬ãH
èC¿Ï%;iØc,£Ì¬>d`úB+ú-7}Æi>®el;sÆ¨]Çê­Ç7£KJöè÷BÇ¡éËÏWZwÚíßÑ`pQXýþáð!ýlòítzÐnßNºÝ=µôso[AÓp(1«G·äågéO¯Z­ÇÚÂÂ¼éÛSñÓÁ`ãjtÏËlÐ Vv#QÀbV¯b8¥,º'¬®¢ùét0Øð²4u¯×ªÝ(`ÅéUòV³NVJ¯¾Å¯8ü°¬$½J¶¶ëdíMì5íõÞu0°¬øWbÚísLìå#WòòoqÈ"çÓBûé*Í¤Ó_V,Ì¨Ê¨¼QÆÞVYûÉ¬ÄKuaïöææ'tügEln^^`v½QÍ¯­E$KÓ3²üü¶YæÑ÷ßÚ
í±ìÃºqcléM&VWÿ1ôû?HÞ14ríÚùáðÉäË¯ÆïI¶87+{¬Û ZiÉBQéZÆ3V(º$í´Bh'o¤øyC²ÍZKØËV]Æ¶j¤¿óÒÂ|CÞñn©b°íAàÖ½Ûãñ  Ò«/§Ó"ò«Õ:Õí>Ûëí£ÑKÖ_qÐ;F9HdädÕJÎ('öHPÞ@ýfmp([{CEJ´[ûT¯bl=Ö²¶Ý¯%ökÉ\×dz??ûÁ¬áð  Ò+"zåsÃáÓéAü»}<íö¹áðáööþhôñSK¥÷s0ÝÊeômÄjS&m¡¤S@¢« Úå}*¬Å+cl»®Âc
³]«a¼vNöäg.`    W¯(æ77/O&$ûhuõ|¯·3oÿh+¦DnäB1Ú#¹q«¡ì×SÐ%7×îÝ§4Ç  ùHpË¤ur9ÏKÊ³ïàÝ[­3D´·÷?¡,a´"¢ÝÝGÂ1AîÕé·,&¿ãËä1;IìaT¬y+WxÃCläl»k@\¼Î5*ÒÆa-/_>ît¶ùg®L§ÛÛû±ü¯Ùé4÷|¦ÏMøDW×eD¥ro¹d=B]:y#T´¶êeaYû]Òf¬*JÐ;~p/?_îu»oÅëîÁY]ýÉ÷^ùUd1TE    =ÒNC¡è/?4yîån¿KßÛÛkÄÂÂwBýi)óÎf&wºý÷°îÒt6°ÖûS{ ¡C¶.×5Mîtÿ?U%¨
ÎæëÄà½¯ uYOôZÆMÌp£aó=u+\    öSÝ¥ë°§ÏïÒ3%QR§·¡4f}¥?ïËz(Rd¿ºräUf$RT»8¡N   Ë¼Òã?{¢lÌ*ìdI´n\Ñ~bERFX¿ôo³v6ëÙ¯](ÇZFâyÒlôüàNö;£9CUÜ½3=%Ô³äf¨lqTÊëÅô«.£IÂ<(«SéøÄÍ(_¾Ëè±<Û®_ùç%ËóòÚõDI·º0ÓLCÖ8.­r$CS"'ëÎ¼îò²qÖ´N¿ø [íäKØö<zó'>AúÌ³°\×hÊ×ÅÇ¹"á4M^ØI²~mW\W(Y9)Ò«R¿m
In¯çkµA9È§2ë©÷ù²²ãwefµ(gÛé_Î+TÄx&>PlÎZèe2Ó~7ÖW©Ö3^×ÔçVéõ 
ôânÀ|A1ÞÉ^;ãôì[ØvÅ«~63ºxíJ/ëe²lF¶U¤ù¹Ö`DÎ®ËÞè»³"ùà¼NX¸0f
×iiqÚQ¿Ew@cAÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ,@m@ÀÔ'?/ó7W¡ óÚk¯½óÎ;ÉÇÇÖë¯¿^= åqõöÛoÏÍÍUk
ð<Î°­³ÏéÃÃÃôçë×¯We
ðÌ)ëöíÛU<ØÖ¨
ÿ/æ7JãpTÙIEND®B`
```

Here my code
The index calling ajax
**index.html**

```
$(document).ready( function()
   {
        //RESET MODAL CONTENT
        resetModal("#myModal");

        $("#btn_pdf").click(function(event) {
            pdf_requerimiento("usuario", "tipo_maquina", "patente", "codigo_codelco", "hr_inicio", "hr_termino", "fecha", "hr_solicitud", "hr_operador", "hr_gps", "rendimiento_gps", "rendimiento_operador", "rendimiento_maquina", "rendimiento_usuario");
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

**The Ajax**

```
    function pdf_requerimiento(usuario, tipo_maquina, patente, codigo_codelco, hr_inicio, hr_termino, fecha, hr_solicitud, hr_operador, hr_gps, rendimiento_gps, rendimiento_operador, rendimiento_maquina, rendimiento_usuario) {  
        form = new FormData();

        form.append("action", "pdf_requerimiento");
        form.append("usuario", usuario);
        form.append("tipo_maquina", tipo_maquina);
        form.append("patente", patente);
        form.append("codigo_codelco", codigo_codelco);
                  **...**
        $.ajax  ({
                data        : form
                cache       : false,
                type        : "post",
                url         : "pages/pdf/controller.pdf.php",
                processData : false,
                contentType : false,
                success     : function(data)
                {
                    /*window.open(
                    'data:application/pdf,'+encodeURIComponent(data)
                    );*/        
                },
                   error        : function(data){ alert('Error');
                } 
   });
}
```

**The controller**

```
function requerimiento(){
        //Variables
        $usuario = $_REQUEST["usuario"];
        $maquina = $_REQUEST["tipo_maquina"];
                     **...**
        $pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',16);
        $pdf->Cell(190,10,'Detalle del Requerimiento','B',2);

        $pdf->Output('I','requerimiento_pdf.pdf');
        /*
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="requerimiento_pdf.pdf');
        */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In php

header("Content-type:application/pdf");

and after

$pdf->Output('I','requerimiento_pdf.pdf');

First you have to set header. And only after that output document.